# How to create a css class for category tags?

Tags: css

I'm wondering how to create the CSS class for tags like the blue boxes around the tags on this site only with adding rounded edges as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/X57p4/2/).

```
.tag {
    background-color: #EEF; /* Set the background color */
    border-radius: 3px;     /* Add some roundness */
    border: 1px #CCF solid; /* Add a border */
    padding: 2px 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```